# Fade in fade out images with scroll then scroll page content

Tags: javascript, html, css

When my page loads there is an image that will appear. What I want to do is on scroll, fade out that image and fade in another image. While this animation is happening, I don't want the images to be scrolled up. It's only when the second image has **faded in completely** that I want to be able to scroll to the content that follows on the page.

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596289/7524152) to come up with part of a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/0pLm6vxc/).

html

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mainImg">
            <img src="images/1.png" style="height: 100%">
        </div>
        <div id="brandStatement">
            <img src="images/2.png" style="height: 100%">
        </div>      
    </div>

    <img src="images/map.png">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

js

```
let locked         = false,
    mainImage      = document.getElementById('mainImg'),
    brandStatement = document.getElementById('brandStatement');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (!locked) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {

            brandStatement.style.opacity = Math.min(window.scrollY / window.innerHeight, 1);
            
            if (brandStatement.style.opacity === '1') {
                    // scroll to next content
            }

            locked = false;
        });
    }
    locked = true;
});
```

css

```
#container {
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100%;
}

#mainImg {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#brandStatement {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you add a snippet of your code..

Comment: @Gass I updated the post with my code

Comment: can you explain this "While this animation is happening, I don't want the images to be scrolled up. It's only when the second image has faded in completely that I want to be able to scroll to the content that follows on the page" in more detail? I don't get it. And also, I don't see the conection between what you want and the answer you found. I see a square moving from one side to the other.. What has that to do with your question?

Comment: [1] @Gass ok I will try to explain it as clearly as I can. When my page loads, there is a photo that covers the whole screen. Usually when you scroll, the content of the page is supposed to scroll up(which is normal behavior). What I wanted to do is for the content to not actually scroll at that point. The scroll is supposed to be bound to a fade-in animation. When the second photo has completely faded in and covered the first photo, then the scroll can scroll to the next content (3rd photo).

Comment: [2] @Gass For now I have managed to do this by using the first photo as background, and second photo as sticky and using a very long container. This is the only solution I have found so far and not sure it's the best one. You can see a lot of these animations on Apple's products pages (iPhones, Macs, etc..). Please check the jsFiddle I included; I managed to adapt the solution of the square moving from one side to the other to part of what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see a possible solution to the problem by improving your code. This is a personal approach.

What I'm doing here, is changing the opacity of the element `one` inside the `cover` container as the user scrolls down the page, revealing the image below. After the opacity changes have been done, the script will change the `filling` container display style property from `none` to `block`. This element is just meant to fill the upper side of the `cover` container to prevent it from moving up when the `position` style property is changed from `fixed` to `null`.

And the reversed logic applies when scrolling back up.

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one')
const cover = document.getElementById('cover')
const filling = document.getElementById('filling')

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let scrollY = window.scrollY
  let bottomHeight = window.innerHeight
  
  if(scrollY / bottomHeight <= 1){
    one.style.opacity = 1 - ( scrollY / bottomHeight )
    cover.style.position = 'fixed'
    filling.style.display = 'none'
  }
  else{
    cover.style.position = null
    filling.style.display = 'block'
  }
})
```

```css
*{padding:0;margin:0;border-size: border-box}

body{
  height: 3500px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#filling{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%
}
#cover{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
#cover > div{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
#one{
  z-index:2;
}
#two{
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id='filling' style='display:none'>
  </div>

  <div id='cover' style='position:fixed'>
    <div id='one'>
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/200/1000/1000'>
    </div>

    <div id='two'>
      <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/201/1000/1000'>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/206/1000/1000'>
  </div>

  <div style='margin-top:-10px'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/204/1000/1000'>
  </div>

  <div style='margin-top:-10px'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/208/1000/1000'>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: brilliant solution!

Comment: Thanks. I made some improvements to the code.